# Modifying a boolean mask with another mask in python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to modify an existing mask for further use in my code according to some condition:

```
import pylab
mask1 = arange(10) > 5;
# [False False False False False False  True  True  True  True]
mask2 = arange(10) >8;
# [False False False False False False False False False  True]
mask1[mask2] = False
print mask1
[ True False False False False False  True  True  True  True]
```

As you see it was the first element the one that was modified and not the last one as expected. What is the right way to do this?

EDIT: Sorry my bad, as some of you pointed out the code is correct, I don't know what was going on there, I will just delete the question.

Comment: When I try your exact code, I get the expected result `[False False False False False False  True  True  True False]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. I have tried it, and it produces the correct result (which is different to the result you show).

Here is an alternative way to do the same thing:

```
mask1 &= ~mask2
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you could construct the mask like this:

```
mask1= logical_and(arange(10)>5,arange(10)<=8)
```

Or even more simply:

```
mask1 = (arange(10)>5) & (arange(10)<=8)
```